# Still Need To Write a Connection Pool Class in J2EE 6 with MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm looking around trying to see if anybody has asked this before. I don't think so.

Some of the other questions I've looked at seem to talk about this a bit and indicate that using a JNDI datasource setup in Tomcat is the best way to do database stuff in your J2EE app now.

It's been three or four years since I did any serious J2EE development. Coming fro .Net and ASP I always thought this need to write your own connection pool was silly. I want to know if you still need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are publicly available libraries that implement connection pooling at a variety of levels.

You might want to take a look at [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/), or just head for Google.